# Uniform convergence when $a \lt b$ but not if $a \geq b$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum, pointwise-convergence

Define the functions $f_k : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_k(x) = k^ax \exp(−k^bx)$ where $a, b \gt 0$. How do I show that $f_k$ converges to $0$ uniformly if $a \lt b$ and that it does not converge uniformly if $a \geq b$? How do I find $||f_k||_\infty $?

For $a \lt b$ it seems quite intuitive as $\exp(-k^bx)$ $\to$ $0$ faster than $k^ax$ $\to$ $\infty$ however, how do I actually formalize this? Am I supposed to be using the M-test here?

Comment: **Hint:** Where's $f_k'(x) = 0$?

Comment: @prets it's going to be a $\frac{1}{k^b}$. If I plug this in $f_k$ will this give me the supremum norm, and I can continue with the M-test?

Comment: That's the $x$-value for which $f_k(x)$ is at its largest. How does that point move as $k$ changes, in your two cases?

Comment: If k increases, the point will move closer to 0?  How can I use this to show the uniform convergence?@prets

Comment: Yes the point $x = 1/k^b$ moves toward $0$, and in case $a < b$ we have $f_k(1/k^b) \to 0$ (this is important, for your uniform convergence). But in the other case..?

Comment: So if $a \lt b$, the largest value will tend to 0, and if $a \geq b$, the largest value will tend to $\infty$ if $n \to \infty$ Does this show the uniform converge?

Comment: Yep. You got it.

Comment: So the M-test is not necessary here then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ f_k'(x) = k^a \exp(-x k^b) (1 - x k^b). $$
This is zero when $x = 1/k^b$, and by checking the second derivative we see this is a maximum.
Hence the largest $f_k(x)$ can be is
$$ f_k(1/k^b) = k^{a - b} \exp(-1). $$
Now observe that if $a < b$, then the exponent in $k^{a - b}$ is negative, so the maximum of $f_k(x)$ is shrinking to zero in this case. Hence $f_k \to 0$ uniformly.

On the other hand if $a \geq b$, the exponent is nonnegative, whence the maximum of $f_k(x)$ goes to infinity (or possibly stays at $\exp(-1)$ if $a = b$), meaning the convergence here is not uniform.